# Display name on the dates inside a calender in VUEJS

Tags: vuejs2

I want to display the title on the calendar on the page, but the title is not displaying.

Here is the HTML code for it:

```
          <div class="card-body pb-0">
            <full-calendar
              ref="refCalendar"
              :options="calendarOptions"
              class="full-calendar"
            />
          </div>
```

And in the script I have this:

```
  components: {
    FullCalendar,
    CalendarEventHandler,
  },
  data(){
    return {
      events:[]
    }
  },
  methods:{
    retrieveTutorials() {
      UserDataService.getAll()
          .then((response) => {
            this.users = response.data.data;
            for (const dataValue of Object.values(this.users)) {
              this.name = dataValue.user_name
              var date = dataValue.created_at
              this.events = [
              {
                title: this.name,
                date: moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
              }
            ]
            }
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
            this.show = true
          });
    },
  },
  computed:{
    calendarOptions: {
      plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin ],
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
      events: this.events,
    }
  },

  mounted () {
    this.retrieveTutorials()
  }
}
```

Currently, the calendar is displaying but the names are not displaying on inside the dates but when consoling the events, the data are coming.

Here is the response from the dataservice:

```
    data: [
             0:{
                "id":"22e9ae0a-b4e0-4b8b-99d2-1a133bb572b8",
                "user_name":"test",
                "address":"xxxxxxxxx",
                "event_name":"test 1",
                "created_at":"2021-05-19T12:00:00Z",
                },
                 1:{
                "id":"22e9ae0a-b4e0-4b8b-99d2-1a133bb572b8",
                "user_name":"test 1",
                "address":"xxxxxxxxx",
                "event_name":"test 1",
                "created_at":"2021-05-20T12:00:00Z",
                },
            ]
```

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated solution link** : https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-sun-jkc4d?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Probably you  dont pass this.events to your component after resolve       UserDataService.getAll()
You can try to take out your  "calendarOptions" in computed property

```
calendarOptions: {
    plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin ],
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
     events: [],
 }
```

as

```
computed: {
    calendarOptions () {
      return {
        plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        events: this.events
      }
    }
  },
```

In data you need write `events: []` and you get this

```
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      events: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    retrieveUsers () {
      UserDataService.getAll()
        .then((response) => {
          const usersData = response.data.data
          for (const dataValue of Object.values(usersData)) {
            const userName = dataValue.user_name
            const eventDate = dataValue.created_at
            this.events = [
              {
                title: userName,
                date: moment(eventDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
              }
            ]
          }
        })
    }
  },
  computed: {
    calendarOptions () {
      return {
        plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        events: this.events
      }
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.retrieveUsers()
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: i updated the code and now its giving: ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'events' of undefined```

Comment: Sorry! I've made mistake and  i've edited my solution. 
Let's try new version :)

Comment: Its still the same. (I have edited it in the questions too.)

Comment: I have this sample one https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-waterfall-2dbnv?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: Ok. 
Can you tell me this.users is object or array ?
Are you want to show date and title of event for each user on calendar?
Can you show for me response which you get from UserDataService.getAll ?

Comment: yes for each user based on the created_date. For the response I have added/edited it to the question above.

Comment: I mocked your network data and create solution
You will need edit my code and replace my mockData for data from UserDataService.getAll() request
https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-sun-jkc4d?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue